# How to set printer properties using vb.net

Tags: vb.net, printing, interop, word-2007

I am using [EDRAW](https://www.edrawsoft.com/embed-word-vbnet.php) to browse a Microsoft Word and can be `Print , Preview , ETC..`. And I am planning to add some features to it. I am adding 2 buttons for `Print Short (8.5 by 11 inches)` and `Print Long (8.5 by 13 inches)` and I have 2 printers for long and short. How to set the properties of the printers in  each button?. If I click button short it will print short using printer 1 same as the button long but it is in printer 2.

I am following the code in the Link provided above.

Anyone has an idea about it?. Any suggestion well help and well be accepted. Thanks.. Cheers.. I will give a 50 bounty to it after two days..

**Code as @Hadi request**

Here is my button code for print.

```
Private Sub btnPrint_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnPrint.Click
    AxEDOffice1.SetActivePrinter("Printer Name")
    AxEDOffice1.ActiveDocument.PageSetup.PaperSize = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdPaperSize.wdPaperA4
    AxEDOffice1.PrintDialog()
End Sub
```

and getting an error *Object variable or With block variable not set* in the line code of `AxEDOffice1.ActiveDocument.PageSetup.PaperSize = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdPaperSize.wdPaperA4`

Comment: VB.NET is not vba - please read the tag text and remove the one that doesnt apply

Comment: @Plutonix sorry about it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set MS Word page size via the automation API?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12620003/how-to-set-ms-word-page-size-via-the-automation-api)

Comment: @Kira you are putting a user answer into your question. i think that people can read his answer. By the way it not a good thing to change your questioon every time get answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After Checking the library all you have to do is using `SetActivePrinter` Method to change your default printer like the following:

```
 AxEDOffice1.SetActivePrinter("Adobe PDF")
```

And to change PaperSize you have to use the following

```
AxEDOffice1.ActiveDocument.PageSetup.PaperSize = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdPaperSize.wdPaperA4
```

`AxEDOffice1.ActiveDocument` is an instance of `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WordDocumentClass`

Code tested it and it works fine.

**EDIT 1:**

> Object variable or With block variable not set

Read more about it on this [MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5szkzs17.aspx) there are many suggestions.

**EDIT 2:**

To Print your document directly without showing `PrintDialog` you have to use `PrintOut` Function.

```
AxEDOffice1.PrintOut(EDOfficeLib.WdPrintOutRange.wdPrintAllDocument)
```

Comment: I got an error.. Value of type Boolean cannot be converted to System.Windows.Form.PrintDialog

Comment: I got this error "Object variable or With block variable not set." in the paper size

Comment: you still there?.. You're the one who almost got my problem :(

Comment: @Kira i tested my code and it worked fine. Can you provide us the code you wrote.

Comment: Ow man :D I focus on print button and I forgot to open first a document that I want to print. Is there a code that direct print? no need to show a dialog print?.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like [Change printername in PrintDialog through code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15641800/change-printername-in-printdialog-through-code) deals with making sure a print dialog box pre-selects the printer based on printer name in vb.net.